# Header redirects stop working after adding PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

Since adding my PDO connection to my db connect.php file all of my header redirects have stopped working. Here is my connect file

**connect.php**

```
<?php 

$connect_error = 'Sorry there is a problem with the database connection.';
mysql_connect('Localhost', 'customn7', 'I<3deadlifts!') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('customn7_cm') or die($connect_error) or die($connect_error);
?>

<?php   

//PDO database connect
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'Localhost',
    'username'  => 'customn7',
    'password'  => 'I<3deadlifts!',
    'dbname'    => 'customn7_cm'
);

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$config['db']['host']. ';dbname=' .$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} 

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
die();
}


?>
```

And here is a redirect that is all of the sudden not working. No HTML has been sent to the browser at this point.

**login.php**

```
// Post Selected name to current class.
if (isset($_POST['exist_to_class'])){
if (empty($_POST['client_data']) === true){
    $errors [] = 'You much select a client to be added to the class.';
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['client_data']) && !empty($_POST['client_data']));
    foreach ($_POST['client_data'] as $cd){
     exist_client_to_class($db, $cd);
     header('Location: view_class.php?class_id='.$class_id.' ');
    } // foreach $cd
} // else

} //isset
```

**init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_NOTICE);


require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/trainer.php';
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php 

$connect_error = 'Sorry there is a problem with the database connection.';
mysql_connect('Localhost', 'customn7', '**********') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('customn7_cm') or die($connect_error) or die($connect_error);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you print something, anything, you are not allowed to send a `header`. You might want to reconsider your error handling.

Comment: Your code is a bit weird, you're trying to set multiple `Location`? If you want to know the error, you could return it in `exist_client_to_class` and pass it to your new `Location`. The point to remember is that you CANNOT `echo` / `print` anything before `Header`

Comment: what do you mean by multiple location?

Comment: why are you using a `foreach`?

Comment: because this pulls data from a checkbox form that the user can select multiple items, each of those items are inserted in db separately. would you like me to post that code as well. they are many other pages throughout the site that have `header` redirects that are single items that do not work as well.

Comment: You might have misunderstood how `Header("Location...")` works, see this thread for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427878/how-to-declare-more-than-one-header-on-php

Comment: I understand how header works just can't figure out what would cause ALL header("location: page.php") to stop working throughout the site. They were working fine before I started messing with my PDO connection. I have removed the PDO script to see if that solved the problem, but it didnt. I just can figure what they would all stop working all the sudden.

Comment: Do you get an output in the browser? Like **any** string?

Comment: notta....I have an `include (init.php)` at the top of all pages and if my header goes before that it works. Something in that file or the included function files is all the sudden causing this issue but I can also not see to get any errors

Comment: I added my init.php code above where it loads all my required files as well as my connect.php file that connect to db. If I comment out `require (database/connect.php);` redirects work but once I uncomment that line they all quit. Any thoughts?