# Not able to redirect to the desired page using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I had created a login form for which the code is below

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['formid'] == 'Form1')
{
  $mysql_server = 'localhost';
  $mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_database = 'register';
mysql_table = 'users';

$db = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username,  $mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if (!$db)
 {
  die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($db,$mysql_database) or die('Failed to select  database<br>'.mysqli_connect_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $active = $row['active'];

   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

   if($count == 1) 
   {   
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

      header("location: home1.php");
      exit;

    }else     {
        echo "Invalid credentials";
    header('Location: home.php');
   exit;
     }

  }
```

The problem with this cide is that I am not able to login . IT just redirects to the login page . It also doesn't  show me any error .
The code of the login form is

```
 <form name="loginform" method="post" action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__);   ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1">
 <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="form1">
 <div id="wb_Text14"    style="position:absolute;left:44px;top:13px;width:412px;height:38px;z-   index:0;text-align:left;">
  <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:27px;">  <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; LOGIN  </strong></span></div>
  <div id="wb_Text15"    style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:75px;width:122px;height:27px;z-  index:1;text-align:left;">
   <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:19px;"><strong> USERNAME</strong></span></div>
  <input type="text" id="Editbox6" style="position:absolute;left:187px;top:75px;width:267px;height:28px;line-  height:28px;z-index:2;" name="username" value="">
    <div id="wb_Text16"    style="position:absolute;left:34px;top:129px;width:125px;height:27px;z- index:3;text-align:left;">
  <span style="color:#000080;font-family:'Comic Sans MS';font-size:19px;"><strong>PASSWORD</strong></span></div>
  <input type="password" id="Editbox7"      style="position:absolute;left:187px;top:129px;width:267px;height:28px;line-    height:28px;z-index:4;" name="password" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit"   style="position:absolute;left:142px;top:223px;width:195px;height:52px;z-index:5;">
      </form>
```

Please help . I am mew to PHP .

Comment: you're outputting before header. Had you been checking for errors, *blah blah blah...*

Comment: plus you left out an important piece of code......... the HTML form

Comment: It's not showing any error

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php there... `headers sent...`

Comment: okay . let m edit it

Comment: This will help with understanding headers and what not as well: [Headers from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427878/how-to-declare-more-than-one-header-on-php) Additionally, if necessary to have delayed headers output buffers will help allowing you to redirect as necessary: [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand . Are you trying to say that I should check for error using these headers ?

Comment: I removed the addition header but still the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting before the header and then the header is already send. Your header should be before everything else.  Also make sure there is no HTML before your login code. And try to use $_SESSION. And your code is open to SQL injection. 
Have a read about headers, $_SESSION and SQL injection on http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

I included the code below. Modify it to your needs.

```
<?php

// Define the core paths
// Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'xampp'.DS.'htdocs'.DS.'yourepage');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');


// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');


// load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
```

?>

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/initialize.php");

if($session->is_logged_in()) {
  redirect_to("index.php");
}

// Remember to give your form's submit tag a name="submit" attribute!
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
    $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $password);

  if ($found_user) {
    $session->login($found_user);
    log_action('Login', "{$found_user->username} logged in");
    redirect_to("index.php");
  } else {
    // username/password combo was not found in the database
    $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
  }

} else { // Form has not been submitted.
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
}

?>

<?php
// A class to help work with Sessions
// In our case, primarily to manage logging users in and out

// Keep in mind when working with sessions that it is generally 
// inadvisable to store DB-related objects in sessions

class Session {

    private $logged_in=false;
    public $user_id;
    public $message;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->check_login();
    if($this->logged_in) {
      // actions to take right away if user is logged in
    } else {
      // actions to take right away if user is not logged in
    }
    }

    public function is_logged_in() {
    return $this->logged_in;
  }

    public function login($user) {
    // database should find user based on username/password
    if($user){
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $this->logged_in = true;
    }
  }

    public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->logged_in = false;
  }

    public function message($msg="") {
        if(!empty($msg)) {
            // then this is "set message"
            // make sure you understand why $this->message=$msg would'nt work
            $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
        } else {
            // then this is "get message"
            return $this->message;
        }
    }

    private function check_login() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
      unset($this->user_id);
      $this->logged_in = false;
    }
  }

    private function check_message() {
        // Is there a message stored in the session?
        if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
            // Add it as an attribute and erase the stored version
            $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        } else {
            $this->message = "";
        }
    }

}

$session = new Session();
$message = $session->message();
```