# php execute chained pages

Tags: php, header

I would to do this :

```
$timeInit = microtime(true);
$bdd = connexionBase();

function ajuste() {
    header('location:ajusteDateFin.php');
}

function transforme() {
    header('location:moulinetteHsConvertionCodeArticle.php');
}

ajuste();
transforme();
echo "<br><br>";
echo microtime(true)-$timeInit;
```

But with this code, only the `transforme()` page is executed. Is there a way to chain them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to redirect to a new page and then redirect again?

Comment: `ajusteDateFin.php` needs to redirect to `moulinetteHsConvertionCodeArticle.php`. I have no idea what code those pages execute but you could opt to `require()`/`include()` or `file_get_contents()` both pages if you are looking to simply benchmark them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare more than one header on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427878/how-to-declare-more-than-one-header-on-php) Specifically the part about "you misunderstand what the HTTP header Location does"

Comment: that's right, execute ajusteDateFin then execute moulinetteHsConvertionCodeArticle

Comment: Why don't you use `require` to call this files in a single request instead?

Comment: I transform data from an old db (access), and I am looking to automate the process.

Comment: Require needs to modify  programs to avoid errors

Comment: What about making cURL requests?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding an header at the end of the first page but this doesn't satisfy me as I have to do a modification on the first page.
I am surprise to can't do simply the execution of chained pages.

Answer (score 0):

To chain php pages, I found a solution, not really esthetic but it do the job.
I add a piece of html code on each php page and call the next one with a little javascript script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location ='http://xxxx';
}
```